# Why can users down-vote without an explnanation or if they don't understand the issue?

Tags: feature-request, down-votes

Sometimes users down-vote if they don't understand the issue, but others did, also vote to close. There are many different minds over the world. What I said, maybe you don't realize it but maybe and maybe not others know what I meant.

**If the programmers had the same minds, there'd be no Google, no Yahoo!, no Microsoft, no Facebook, even Stack Overflow would never exist.** The people are not on the same mind. Up-vote means I have the same issue, I agree with you. But down-vote seems like I don't like your question, I don't realize your mind. If you don't agree, just leave. Maybe someone else knows what the question means.

I think Stack Overflow needs to help programmers, but down-vote the helpless. Tt is help for the others, but not for the one who has the question.

**Why is Stack Overflow still using down-votes? Is it help to the one who has questions? Even on meta, which was supposedly founded to discuss Stack Overflow issues.**
I think I will receive an answer saying "For person like you".

Comment: You tagged this as feature-request. What do you want to change or add?

Comment: change vote-down

Comment: You may also want to review [how downvotes on meta work](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/help)

Comment: @rene he want to remove the whole downvote system i.e. user will not be able to downvote, only upvote.

Comment: @ShadowWizard yes, that what I want

Answer (score 13):

Downvotes are our best signal for poor quality posts.

Not everyone with the privilege to downvote has the privilege to close, and sometimes people who do have the privilege to close have run out of votes.

Putting a requirement to add a comment as a reason for the downvote means we will get less downvotes, meaning we will not have as clear a signal as to the poor quality of the post and more low quality posts will remain on the site. This is not a good thing.

Comment: the poor quality of the post will never helps the programmer himself

Comment: @SaifHamed - we need to think about more than individuals. If Stack Overflow were to end up with more low quality posts than good quality, then it would not longer be a good resource for programmers. Is that what you want?

Comment: no. but, hmmmmm okey I got it.

Comment: @SaifHamed In addition to Oded's very good answer; sometimes people don't think a question is 'bad enough' to close, but is enough to down vote.

Comment: @SaifHamed - I also recommend reading ["Optimizing for Pearls, Not Sand"](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/06/optimizing-for-pearls-not-sand/) to understand some of the reasoning behind this.

Comment: @AndrewBarber I see.

Comment: @BradLarson I read it. Now I should vote-down what I think is not a clear question. Not just leaving as I was. ;)